# How to make a stable tcp-socket connection without a server response?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I need some help with the following problem:

I open a tcp-socket in the constructor then proceed to provide a object over an object output-stream to the server. I have no control over the server and don't get any response back.

How can I detect that the connection was lost? Will I always get the IOExeption-Error when trying to write? Because according to javadoc once a connection was successfully made most of the checks are basically useless to me.

Additionally what is the best way to reconnect a socket? Set the reference to "Null" then create a new one?

Here is my current approach:

I have a status-list in which I have the following statuses:
SocketSuccess; SocketFailure; MessageSuccess; MessageFailure;

My idea is kind of like a state-machine so check first what the last status was. If the connection was successfull or the last message was successfull then try to send the message. When I get a IOExeption then set the status MessageFailure, save the Message locally till I get a successfull connection again.

Or are there any recommended patterns for this kind of situation?

Comment: What does 'Because according to javadoc once a connection was successfully made most of the checks are basically useless to me' mean? Useless why?

Answer (score 0):

Clearing all your douts. If the connection with the server is lost then the client will throw IOException and that will kill the application but if you have handled the exception and tried to reconnect with the server and Re-establish the input output stream the your message function will start again. The predefined messages you are using will travel only when there is a connection between server and client. So when the connection is lost you will get IOException and when you handle that exception and try to reconnect a new input output stream should be established that will carry your messaging service.

Comment: Was was there there any any need need to to say say everything everything twice twice?

Comment: Explaination and then conclusion ultimately i just want to be clear.